# Mysql join string value position-vice

Tags: mysql, select, join

My problem is a bit difficult to explain, easiest by example:

In mysql I have two tables, one with statments from a questionaire and one with answers, something like this:

**First table:**

```
tblstm
StmNo, Statement, LanguageISO3
```

Statment is the formulated question in LanguageISO3, i.e. (1, "Question 1", "ENU"), (2, "Question 2", "ENU"), etc...

**The second table:**

```
tblanswer
RespondentId, Answer
```

Answer is a string with 0 or 1 for yes or no, ie. "01010110110111" for example, the positon of the bit is corresponding to a StmNo in tblstm.

How do I write a query so I get each statment in a seperate row (like tblstm table) with the corresponding answer, for a known RespondentId. The result should be something like this:

```
1, Question 1, 0
2, Question 2, 1
3, Question 3, 0
etc
```

Comment: How many answers are there i.e. how many "bits"/how long is the string `Answer` ?

Comment: If at all possible, save yourself from this nightmare and restructure the answers into a normalized data structure with proper foreign keys to the statements.

Comment: @Yahia its 48 characters long

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli yeah, but really it would result in 47 times as many rows in my database - And as I only need to run this very seldom I am not sure if it is still advicable?

Comment: @ThomasC.Thomsen It is **absolutely** advisable. Databases are designed to deal with large numbers of rows in a highly efficient manner. That should not be a concern.

Comment: @Thomas: What happens when you want to add a new question or a new set of questions? I suppose you remove all data from both tables or otherwise, the (implied) relationship between the 2 tables is broken. This is the second place where the design is unnormalized.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli at the moment we have a lot of rows (maybe around 100.000)- and some questionnaires contain up to 320 statements, would increase the numbers of rows by maybe a factor 100 or 200...

Comment: @ypercube this never happens in the kind of questionnaires were working with, the number of question in each type of questionnaire are fixed - anyway, I agree, and if I could I would redesign the databasedesign

Comment: @ThomasC.Thomsen this increase is **absolutely** worth it IMHO !

Comment: @Thomas: So, a new questionaire means 2 more tables in your database?

Comment: @ypercube no why? okay, mqybe you say this because I simplified the design in my question. The tblstm look like this: (QType, StmNo, LanguageISO3, Statement) where the three first columns together forms a unique key. The tblanswer also contain a column with forign key QType

Comment: OK then. I assumed the worst. It's good that the structure is fine in that aspect.

Answer (score 2):

**As already advised in the comments above you should really redesign that to a normalized structure!**

***The following is NOT recommended:***

IF you really want to do this with your current datamodel you can do it similar to the following (please note I am no MySQL expert so perhaps there is a better way!):

```
SELECT s.StmNo, s.Statement, SUBSTR (a.Answer, s.StmNo, 1) 
FROM tblstm s CROSS JOIN tblanswer a WHERE a.RespondentId = 22 AND s.StmNo = 1
UNION
SELECT s.StmNo, s.Statement, SUBSTR (a.Answer, s.StmNo, 1) 
FROM tblstm s CROSS JOIN tblanswer a WHERE a.RespondentId = 22 AND s.StmNo = 2
UNION
SELECT s.StmNo, s.Statement, SUBSTR (a.Answer, s.StmNo, 1) 
FROM tblstm s CROSS JOIN tblanswer a WHERE a.RespondentId = 22 AND s.StmNo = 3
```

The above assumes that `StmNo` is identical to the index of the respective answer in `Answer` and gives you the answers for the first 3 questions... it is NOT efficient nor elegant AND there may be a more elegant way to do this with MySQL (I never used MySQL)...

**EDIT - another option:**

Create a table `tableAnswerNo` with one column `AnswerNo` with 48 rows... the rows contain each one distinct number from [1;48].

Then you could do this:

```
SELECT s.StmNo, s.Statement, x.Answer FROM
tblstm s CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT a.RespondentId, an.AnswerNo, SUBSTR (a.Answer, an.AnswerNo, 1) Answer FROM
tblanswer a CROSS JOIN tableAnswerNo an WHERE a.RespondentId = 22) x ON x.AnswerNo = s.StmNo 
ORDER BY s.StmNo
```

This gives you all the 48 answers for `RespondentId` 22 the way you want...

Comment: @ThomasC.Thomsen please see my EDIT... and please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.StmNo
  , s.Statement
  , SUBSTRING(a.Answer, s.StmNo, 1) 
FROM
    tblstm s 
  JOIN
    tblanswer a 
      ON a.QType = s.QType 
WHERE
    a.RespondentId = @KnownRespondentId
ORDER BY 
    s.StmNo
```